# Health check page in Code Igniter: Return non-200 status code on any PHP error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement a simple health check page (to use with ELB). It connects to the **database**, loads a **model**, and returns a 200 status code if everything is OK, and a non **200 status** code if something goes wrong.

The problem that I am having is that Code Igniter seems to return a 200 status code when non fatal PHP errors are encountered. Can I modify that behaviour (if possible only for a specific controller)?

To be clear, currently I get a 200 status code even when there's an error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>   Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'X'@'Y' (using password: YES)
>   Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>   Line Number: 202

I want to return a non 200 in this case (bc that's what makes sense for a health check page).

Any ideas?

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html

Comment: @DainisAbols Thanks for your input. I assume you are referring to set_status_header(), but how would you do it (e.g. custom error handlers)?

Comment: I would guess: create a test like method which suppresses errors and sets it' s own header based on responses? `if(db_connect===true) $header=200; else $header=400;`

Comment: OK, that's a possibility! It's a bit suboptimal bc you have to explicitly list all the things you want to test for. Whereas if I can just say 'send a 500 status code for any warning', I automatically test the autoloads, the DB connection, MY_Controller, etc...